# Closed contour integral of function $ f(z)=\frac{1}{z} $

Tags: complex-analysis

The contour integral around a circle of radius R with function as in the title is given to be $ 2 \pi i $. However the circle is a close contour, why isn't it 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Cauchy's integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_theorem) only applies if $f$ is holomorphic over a **simply connected** region that contains the contour.  For our $f(z)$, this is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

$f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ is not analytic at $z = 0$. That's mainly the reason.

Answer (score 1):

You're circleling a pole (at $z=0$). Therefore it is not possible to contract the contour to a single point, you MUST evaluate the integral. 
By getting the Laurent-Series of the integrand and getting the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ and multiply it by $2 \pi i$.